# SQL add column value based on another column ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

What I'm trying to do is add another column to an existing table whose value will depend on an already existing column in the table. For example say I have this table:

```
 Table1

|Letter|
   A
   C
   R
   A
```

I want to create another column (for example, numbers) that is chosen based on the letters. So let's say A corresponds with 10, C with 3 and R with 32 (this was chosen at random). My resulting table should be like this:

```
|Letter| Number |
   A   |   10
   C   |   3
   R   |   32
   A   |   10
```

Can anyone help me write a query that does this..I have over 20 different cases, so the simpler it looks the better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What/where is the logic by which `10` is associated with `A` etc.?

Comment: I just randomly made that up...it was used to clarify what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Build a table that associates [Letter] with the numeric value. Include this table in query by joining on the common [Letter] fields.
2. A very long Switch() expression. However, query design grid cell has a limit of 1024 characters.

Better to provide example with your real data and criteria.

Comment: I'll do the first option. Thanks for the idea!